# Run all MsTest tests according to convention

Tags: teamcity

My test libraries are called according to convention Something.Tests.dll. Is there any way to specify *.Tests.dll instead of enumerating all the assemblies one be one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it appears that TeamCity does support wildcards in the "List assembly files" field, even though `mstest`'s `/testcontainer` argument does not. Make sure to familiarise yourself with some defects in the TeamCity wildcard implementation listed in [TW-24220](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24220).